# How to tell if any element in a list of combinations is in a specific set in the most efficient way?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, coding-style

here is what i mean by the question:

```
j = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
k = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

#I want to generate all possible pairs of pairs with these two lists, for 
example: 
p1 = (1,1)
p2 = (2,2)
pairA = (p1,p2) # (1,1),(2,2)
#This is what i mean by pair of pair

#This is what I've got so far:

sA = set()         #this has a lot of pairs of pairs in it
sA.add(...)
#...

for item in permutations(j):
    for m1,m2 in combinations(zip(item,k),2):
           if (m1,m2) in sA:   # I want to know quickly 
                               # if any pair(of pairs) 
                               # the combination produces 
                               # is in set sA
               #do stuff
           else:
               #do some other stuff
```

This part of my code scales badly with the number of elements in list j,k increases. I wonder is there specific way in python to make it more efficient in terms of performance or cleaner in style. It looks very clumsy to me.

Any idea and advice will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you constructing the pairs, does order matter, e.g. are `(2, 1)` and `(1, 2)` different pairs? What about pairs of pairs, is `((1, 2), (1, 3))` different to `((1, 3), (1, 2))`. Wouldn't this provide it for you: `list(itertools.permutations(itertools.product(j, k), 2))` (or `itertools.combinations()`)

Comment: yes it should be different. The current code yields what I want but it is very slow when input size gets big. I wonder is there a better way to do it. @AChampion

Comment: You construction generates lots of duplicates and seems to miss certain pairs (e.g. `((1,1), (1,2))`) `itertools.product(j, k)` generates all the pairs, `itertools.permutations(pairs, 2)` generates all pairs of pairs (assuming you want to avoid `((1,1), (1,1))` as a pair of pairs).

Comment: That actually solves my problem! Thank you very much